# Optimizing power consumption at server farm

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, operations-research

I have the following task.I'll need to optimize power consumption on some server farm and the servers need to auto scale depending on the historical usage.I wondered what would be a good way of thinking about the problem and then I though of calculus of variations and the shortest path problem.I want to describe the auto-scale algorithm as a shortest path on the CPU usage axis vs time.It will be subject to some constraints such as time for launching a new instance.Imagine the picture below shows CPU usage (x(t)) vs time.

[image]

I have a few questions :

Is calculus of variations suitable for dynamical systems such as this one ?I can get a decent looking function from the data and make a good approximation, but is it a good idea to look at my problem from this angle ? 
Is calculus of variations only applicable in physics and engineering ?

I am new to calculus of variations, so please be gentle :) I am seeking for more intuition on the subject rather than hardcore theory.

Comment: You need to be clear what you are optimising. Why not turn the server off to use zero power! There is probably some cost to not having enough CPUs online and a cost (in terms of power) of having too many. Also, as you say, you have constraints like it takes x seconds to add a CPU and y to remove it,  else you could chose the CPU count continuously. Calculus of variation is not so good with inequality type constraints.  Try integer programing techniques.

Comment: Calc. of var. definitely lives outside of physics and engineering, you would say there is a whole mathematics to it and that physics and engineering happen to have some useful problems that it can solve. For instance the concept of geodesics on a manifold.

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys.So I suppose calc of variations is not the best option here, although it sounded like a good candidate.

Comment: I would consider a time-series or predictive analytics approach due to the fact that you need to base it on historical data. Consider eg https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/cka/Predictive-Analytics-Microsoft-Excel-Conrad-Carlberg/0789749416